# Local servicefabric cluster no longer shown in server explorer in visual studio

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I just upgraded the ServiceFabric SDK to version 1.5.175. In Visual Studio (2015) I no longer see the Local cluster in the Server Explorer.

Questions:
1) How can I add the Local cluster to the Server Explorer?
2) Is there another way to see the diagnostics log in Visual Studio (or elsewhere).

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 2):

Going forward, the best experience for interacting with Azure resources (including the Service Fabric local cluster) in Visual Studio is [Cloud Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/84e83a7c-9606-4f9f-83dd-0f6182f13add).

You can also bring up the diagnostic viewer from View > Other Windows > Diagnostic Events Viewer.